# How to measure dimensions in RViz

Tags: rviz, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i use RViz measure tool to get dimensions of all the complex shapes in my model. Or is there any other method to do so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100806/how-to-measure-dimensions-in-rviz/) by [Akshay_Bhardwaj_nsit](https://answers.ros.org/users/8321/akshay_bhardwaj_nsit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there is an option "select " which dispalys the coordinates

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1